# Picture upload in Ionic 4 with camera and file plugins

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4

I am trying to upload file in Ionic 4 to the server but getting the error `2nd parameter must be blob`.

But I have logged the blob image it is coming properly.

I am following in this https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-image-upload-storage/ this link for the guide.

I don't need to save this to local storage so I have skipped that section.

```js
selectImageInGallery() {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    };
    this.camera.getPicture(options).then(
      imageData => {
        const formData = this.uploadAvatar(imageData);
        this.uploadAvatar(formData);
      },
      err => {
        this.toastService.presentToastBottom('Failed to select the image');
      }
    );
  }

uploadAvatar(imagePath: any) {
    let fileName = '';
    this.file
      .resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(imagePath)
      .then(fileEntry => {
        const { name, nativeURL } = fileEntry;
        const path = nativeURL.substring(0, nativeURL.lastIndexOf('/'));
        fileName = name;
        return this.file.readAsArrayBuffer(path, name);
      })
      .then(buffer => {
        const imgBlob = new Blob([buffer], {
          type: 'image/jpeg'
        });
        console.log(imgBlob);
        const formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('avatar', imgBlob);
        this.userService.updateAvatar(formData).then(res => {
          console.log(res);
          this.loader.hideLoader();
          // if (res.data.status === 'success') {
          //   this.user = res.data.user;
          // } else if (res.data.status === 'error') {
          //   this.toastService.presentToast(res.data.message);
          // } else {
          //   this.toastService.presentToast('Server Error');
          // }
        });
      });
  }

Service
public async updateAvatar(postData: any) {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'X-Authorization': environment.appKey,
        Authorization: localStorage.getItem('TOKEN_KEY')
      })
    };
    const res = await this.http
      .post(
        environment.apiUrl + 'user/update-profile-picture',
        postData,
        httpOptions
      )
      .toPromise();
    return res as any;
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried uploading the image as a base64 string instead of converting it to a blob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    uploadBase64(imageBase64: any) {
    this.loader.showLoader();
    const blobImg = this.dataURItoBlob(imageBase64);
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('avatar', blobImg, 'image.jpeg');
    this.profileService.updateAvatar(formData).then(res => {
      this.loader.hideLoader();
      if (res.data.status === 'success') {
        this.user.avatar = imageBase64;
      } else if (res.data.status === 'error') {
        this.toastService.presentToast(res.data.message);
      } else {
        this.toastService.presentToast('Server Error');
      }
    });
  }

  dataURItoBlob(dataURI: any) {
    // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
    let byteString: any;
    if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0) {
      byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    } else {
      byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    }
    // separate out the mime component
    const mimeString = dataURI
      .split(',')[0]
      .split(':')[1]
      .split(';')[0];
    // write the bytes of the string to a typed array
    const ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
      ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return new Blob([ia], { type: mimeString });
  }

  async openCertificateUploadPage() {
    const modal = await this.modalCrtl.create({
      component: CertificateUploadPage
    });
    modal.onDidDismiss().then(res => {
      this.getProfile();
    });
    return await modal.present();
  }
```

That is the solutions for that issue. I have figure out.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a good way to solve the issue. Do some research on the base64 option, it uses a lot of memory and crashes devices.

Comment: @rtpHarry excuse me, Do you know what could be the best way to avoid using base64 or the best practice to use? not the code, only the idea. If you have the code would be great. Thanks!

Comment: I would check Devdactic / Ionic Academy, Simon writes great tutorials and I have a feeling he has covered this.

Answer (score 1):

How closely have you followed this tutorial?

As I recall from watching Simon's videos (devdactic author), there are complications working with images where you need to create at least a temporary file on the system to send off to other places.

First, you should follow the tutorial exactly and then once it is working you can experiment with removing things.

In the first section of the tutorial it clearly states:

- Upload files from their **local path** using a POST request

So I don't think just removing chunks of the tutorial is your best technique for getting this going.

Learn from the expert first, modify later.

Comment: Thanks, I have made the blob image and now that is working fine.